# Laravel 5.2 w/ OAuth2: how do I switch routing depending on whether an auth token was sent at all?

Tags: oauth, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-authorization

I have a route that is currently behind the OAuth2 middleware. If someone hits it with a valid auth token, they get the content. If they hit it with an invalid token, they get a 400 error. So far, so good.

The issue is this route serves two purposes. It delivers content to users of a client app, who provide an auth token with their request. But it also serves as a link for sharing content with others. When someone clicks on that link in a browser, they will not supply any auth token. In this case, instead of a 400 error, I want to redirect them to a landing page with a smart banner for deep linking purposes. This way, if they don't yet have the app, it will give them the app store link to download it. If they have the app and are using their mobile device, the deep link will cause the client app to open and go to the specified content (using their auth token).

How do I separate out the OAuth2 behavior for an invalid token vs. no token provided?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why it has to be the same route? The only way i can imagine is to put another middleware right above your oauth middleware. However you will need to adapt the oauth middleware to not fail when there is no token at all.

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer I was coming to. I think I've found a cleaner way. Because the client device registers certain routes for deep linking, I'm going to use a different subdomain for the deep link routes. That subdomain points to a server that has nothing on it except the Apple deep linking file. It redirects everything else to the website. Problem solved.